# Discord.js V14: How can i make my arg not take the rest of the message?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, bots

lets say there was a role with more then just 1 word in it. Ive tried `const roler =  args.slice(2).join(' ')` BUT i also wanna add a "reason": `>addrole @user role reason`.

My codes works perfectly if theres no reason, but the `const roler =  args.slice(2).join(' ')` will
make it take all the rest of the message and idk when to make how to make it stop. (Btw, the code i will show here is just the base of everything and i will make it more complex later):

```
if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix+ 'addrole')) {
            const messagetoarg = msg.content
            const args = messagetoarg.split(' ')
            const member = args[1]
            const roler = args[2]
            console.log(roler)
           

        const uhmaywork =   msg.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roler);
            
        if (uhmaywork && member ===`<@${msg.mentions.members.first().id}>`) {
            const realmember = msg.mentions.members.first()
            console.log('works')
            realmember.roles.add(uhmaywork)
        }
    
    }
```

If i said in chat `>addrole @mycoolalt a role uh this is my reason` then my current code would think that the role name is `a role uh this is my reason` while  its only `a role` and i want the reason to be `uh this is my reason`. because of this my bot wont detect the role and its annoying.

Also, if i accidently add a space ( `a role`) instead of (`a role`) it also wont work.

how do i make my arg cut at some certain point, have a reason and accidental spacing wont matter?

once again this is just the basic of the code ill add more after my question is solved.

thank you and any help is appreciated :D

(man the number of errors is demotivating me so frickin much)

Comment: Your setup is somewhat flawed. We can't really expect Javascript to be able to distinguish a role name from other arguments if they are all words. This is what slash commands were created for. If you *really* want to stick to message commands, use a character to split the arguments up: `!addrole user | role name | reason`; Split the message by `|` then use `.trim()` to remove extra spaces on the end